# Setting up a polycom voip phone that's already configured with it's sip.id

Tags: networking, configuration, polycom

I Work for a call center but I'm moving out of the city, the boss gave me my phone that I use at work. 
Now will the phone automatically configure it's self to the network once I plug it in or do I have to do something special in order for it to work?

Answer (score 1):

If you were using a public IP to connect to voip provider or virtual PBX, you probably won't need to do anything and the phone will work. If you were connecting to a LAN IP (usually a PBX like asterisk) you have many options and it is better to see with the voip/network admin if you'll need a VPN or direct internet connection to connect to the PBX.

Comment: +1 absolutally. VoIP networks can be configured in a hundred different ways and the only way to know is to speak to the person that runs the callcentre's VoIP system